# Access instance via methods inside a custom Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to access the instance methods/data through a triggered method inside a custom registered Vue component.

Below a basic example:

```
Vue.component('example-component', {
        template: `<div>
                        <h2>Count: {{count}}</h2>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="increment()">Increment</button>
                    </div>`,
        data: () => {
            return {
                count: 0
            }
        },
        methods: {
            increment: () => {
                console.log("Click!");
                console.log("Current count: ", this.count);
                this.count++;
                console.log("New count: ", this.count);
            },
            decrement: () => {
                // other function
            }
        },
        mounted: () => {
            console.log("Example component mounted!");
        }
    });
```

Results:

```
Example component mounted!
Click!
Current count:  undefined
New count:  NaN
```

As you might notice the property 'count' has been loaded during the component mount and is available/rendered inside the HTML. The method 'increment()' has also been triggered. However, 'this.count' seems to be unreachable like possible other methods (e.g. 'this.decrement()') which will throw a TypeError this.decrement is not a function.

Any suggestions if this approach is even possible?

PS. I'm aware of the default approach via a .vue file registery like:

```
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);
```

Comment: The methods and hooks such as `mounted`, etc, shouldn't be arrow functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explanation from the official [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/data-methods.html#methods):

> Vue automatically binds the this value for methods so that it always refers to the component instance. This ensures that a method retains the correct this value if it's used as an event listener or callback. **You should avoid using arrow functions when defining methods, as that prevents Vue from binding the appropriate this value.**

The answer above by Phoenix seems to be valid, and I can only add that you can write the functions in a [short form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions) too like:

```
increment() { ... },
decrement() { ... }
```

which looks nicer in my opinion, although there is a slight difference.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. It works and looks nicer indeed!

Answer (score 0):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) don't bind with `this`. Use normal functions instead for your methods.

```js
increment: function() { ... },
decrement: function() { ... }
```